# How to replace Image 'alt' attribute if its blank?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace, alt

I want to replace image alt tags of the content. So I used `preg_replace`

```
add_filter('the_content', 'click_to_expand_gallery');
function click_to_expand_gallery($content) {
        $pattern ='~<a(.*?)href=(.*?)><img(.*?)alt="(.*?)"></a>~i';
        $replacement = '<a$1href=$2><img$3alt="Game"></a>';
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    }
```

It's working fine, but the issue is, this code is replacing the alt tags if it already have data.

Can anyone please guide me about how to check if the alt tag is blank or not and then replace its data according to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only match the fullstring when alt has an empty value.  Capture the two parts that stay unchanged and put them on either side of your default value "Game" in `$replacement`:

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a58ae4a0135dd42a008ff38ad8b46bada8f2ff5)):

```
$pattern ='~(<a.*? href=[^>]*><img.*? alt=")("[^>]*></a>)~i';
$replacement = '$1Game$2';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
echo $content;
```

Input/Output:

```
$content='<a href="something.com"><img src="blah.jpg" alt=""></a>';
// output: <a href="something.com"><img src="blah.jpg" alt="Game"></a>

$content='<a href="something.com"><img src="blah.jpg" alt="Not Empty"></a>'; 
// output: <a href="something.com"><img src="blah.jpg" alt="Not Empty"></a>
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jNRezy/3)

Now, this literally matches an `<a>` tag with an href attribute and that may also have zero or more other attributes, containing an `<img>` tag that must have an empty `alt` attribute and may have zero or more other attributes.

If you don't care to check that the `<img>` tag is nested in an anchor tag, then the regex pattern can be reduced to only match the `<img>` portion.

Comment: Can you please explain me `'~(<a.*?href=[^>]*><img.*?alt=")[^"]{0}("></a>)~i';` this code or any reference tuts.

Comment: @RockySena I need to better refine this pattern.  It works but I didn't have time to optimize.  I am with my family right now.  I'll be back asap.  I'll include explanation.

Comment: Thank you... mickmackusa

Comment: @RockySena The pattern explanation is available in the Pattern Demo link.

Comment: For the record, it is not optimal to use regex on valid html.  When next have a session at my desk, I'll add a domdocument/xpath solution.  (I'm an older and wiser programmer since this answer.)